# Compressing images in an array before doing animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an array of big images (4000x4000) and bigger and I'm looping through these images while doing animation.

The goal here is to compress these images before loading them, but no matter what extension I use, calling      `self.theImage.animationImages` does not work.

Here is my code so far:

```
    let images = [
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageOne"),
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageTwo"),
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageThree"),
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageFour"),
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ImageFive"),
        #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageSix")]



    self.theImage.animationImages = images;
    self.theImage.animationDuration = 10.0
    self.theImage.layer.add(rotatePicture, forKey: nil)
    self.theImage.startAnimating()


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{
        self.theImage.frame.origin.y += 440
    }){_ in

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 2.25, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            self.theImage.frame.origin.y -= 490

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method :

```
func resizeImage(image:UIImage,size:CGSize) ->UIImage
    {

        let sizeconvert:CGSize = CGSize.init(width: 500, height: 300)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,0.0)
        image .draw(in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let scaledImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return scaledImage;
    }
```

Comment: @Divya Thakkar that's the same thing . What change did u make ?